# jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module

Tags: java, maven, openjdk-17

I get the following error after executing command *mvn clean package*:

```
Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x298bfadd) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x298bfadd
```

I am using JDK 17.0.1 and for what I read it was a common error in idk 16. Any ideas how to fix it?
I am working on Mac and my mvn version is 3.8.4

```
% echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Context? Logging output ?

Comment: You are probably running an old version of Lombok.  You need v1.18.22 (October 6th, 2021) or later for Java 17 support; see https://projectlombok.org/changelog

Comment: @StephenC I have Lombok v1.18.22 installed

Comment: Upgrading `org.projectlombok:lombok` to `1.18.24` fixed my issue.